# boto3 create bucket error - Could not connect to the endpoint URL

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using boto3 python module to access S3.

Creating bucket works in windows but not working in ubuntu.

It throws the error given below,

```
botocore.exceptions.EndpointConnectionError: Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/"
```

Sample code:

```
aws_access_key = ""
aws_secret_key = ""
s3_region = "us-east-1"

s3_connection = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key,
                             aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_key,
                             region_name=s3_region)
s3_connection.create_bucket(Bucket='bucket_name')
```

Comment: can you print `s3_connection` and share the log?

Comment: @AtulKumar <botocore.client.S3 object at 0xb6da9acc>

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 732, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Comment: Are you aware that bucket name must be unique, it must not have been used before not by you only.

Comment: yes, bucket name is unique, while using windows os its working

Comment: Have you tried giving some other name ?

Comment: yes.. bot none of them works

Answer (score 0):

The error message is suggesting that `region_name = 'bucket_name'`, which does not match the code you have shown us.

Also, please note that it is considered unwise to put credentials in your source code. Instead you should use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command to store credentials in `~.aws/credentials`. You can then remove them from your code.

You can then run this code to create the bucket:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-east-1')

s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket='foo')
```